# Laplacian variational problem with asymptotically quadratic term

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, calculus-of-variations, critical-point-theory

Consider the functional 
$$J= \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 - \int_\Omega F(u),$$
where $\Omega$ is a bounded smooth domain.

The problem has been solved for example if $F$ is **(1)** *subquadratic*, or **(2)** *superquadratic and subcritical* (in the sense of Sobolev embedding exponents), or **(3)** *asymptotically quadratic*.

- Heuristically, what makes these cases different? And what are the differences among them?
- Where can I find a nicely written discussion on the difference among these cases?
- Is it true that the asymptotically quadratic case separates the case where you can prove existence of a minimizer (subquadratic case) and the one where you can prove that only non-minimizer critical points exist (asymptotically quadratic and superquadratic)?